# How can write names of image / file in excel sheet using matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io

I need to print name of an image or current browsed file in specific position in excel using matlab Here is the code of what I tried so far

```
Image2 = imread('D:\wilyam','jpeg');
aa= {'wilyam'};
xlswrite('D:\aa.xls',aa,'Sheet1','A1');
```

OR ..

when i need to print name of browse image in GUI .. how can i print name of this upload image in excel sheet ...

```
filename=handles.filename;
[X2] = imread(filename);
xlswrite('D:\aa.xls',[X2],'Sheet1','A1');
```

both codes don't write the name of image ... its give me name of variable or some error data ... any help please .

hope to get the following output :

excel sheet1 cell [A1] contain (( name of my image or browsed image name like wilyam or browsed image name ).

Comment: can you please be more specific ? what is wrong with your code ? do you want `aa` variable to be computed automatically ?

Comment: does `xlswrite` succeed to write something ? what is it ? try using it like this `[status,message] = xlswrite()` what is the `status` value and `message`  ?

Comment: thanks for replay .. i updated my question to be more clearly ,,,